# Has any one seen an application of the virial theorem (say with magnetic fields) for non-self gravitating system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-statics, stability, magnetohydrodynamics, virial-theorem

Here is the version of the theorem I am most familiar with - consider an ideal magneto-fluid with density $\rho$, bulk velocity field $\mathbf v$, with magnetic field $\mathbf B$ and (isotropic gas) pressure $p$. Then define various moments with respect to the density,
$$\mathsf I_{ij} = \int d^3x \; \rho(\mathbf x)\; x_i x_j  \ ,$$

$$\mathsf P_{ij} = p(\mathbf x) \; \delta_{ij} \ ,$$

$$ \mathsf K_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} \rho(\mathbf x) \; v_i(\mathbf x) v_j(\mathbf x) \ ,$$

$$ \mathsf M_{ij} = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \left( \frac{1}{2} B^2(\mathbf x) \delta_{ij} - B_i(\mathbf x) B_j(\mathbf x) \right) \ , $$

$$ \mathsf U_{ij} = - \frac{G}{2} \int d^3x \int d^3 x'  \; \rho(\mathbf x) \rho(\mathbf x') \; \frac{\left(x_i - x_i'\right)\left(x_j - x_j'\right)}{|\mathbf x - \mathbf x '|^3} \ .$$

It follows from the ideal MHD equations that,
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2 \mathsf I_{ij}}{dt} = \mathsf U_{ij} + \int d^3 x \; \left( 2 \mathsf K_{ij} + \mathsf P_{ij} + \mathsf M_{ij} \right) \\
\implies  \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2  I}{dt} =  U + \int d^3 x \; \left( 2  K +  3 p +  M \right) \ ,
\end{equation}
where the second equation is the trace of the first and the quantities have physical interpretation of energies - gravitational potential, bulk kinetic, thermal ($p \propto \rho T$, $T$ is temperature) and magnetic respectively. Required modifications can be carried out to include any other force (possibly external) - which will result in the appearance of the moment of that force and work done by it.

In most applications the only negative term on the right-hand side, gravitational potential energy $U$, balances the rest of the positive terms, to attain a steady-state with a vanishing left-hand side. My question is: are there any situations in which $U$ can be neglected (for example in atmospheres over small heights) and yet the theorem is useful?